# Robocopy not to copy files, which are deleted in the destination

Tags: robocopy

We use Robocopy as part of our backup concept.

Now when the destination computer has crashed, we will restore files from our backup/source computer using the backup one hour (which is the related backup interval) ago. However the destination computer might receive files this way, which had been deleted in the meantime by users on the destination server (which acts very dynamic) on purpose.

This is something, we would like avoid. Is this possible with Robocopy? Per my understanding it is not...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the situation correctly it is something like this:
- One hour ago:  your backup is created
- 30 mins ago:  User deletes a file
- 10 mins ago:  server disk crashes
- Now you need to restore from backup

The server hard disk is now gone.  The only information you now have is on the backup from one hour ago. The backup was done before the user deleted the file. So you have no way of knowing that the user deleted the file.

It seems to me that robocopy will not help in this situation, as there is no way to know what files were deleted after the backup was taken.

Does this make sense?